# How to resolve the issue "Can't find import Effects" in Idris?

Tags: idris, nix

I was trying to compile the following "hello world" source file after some time away from Idris using a nix-shell environment ([direction](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/doc/languages-frameworks/idris.section.md)):

```
module Main

import Effects
import Effect.StdIO

hello : Eff () [STDIO]
hello = putStrLn "Hello world!"

main : IO ()
main = run hello
```

My output was as follows during the experimentation; despite specifying what seems to be the right library, I still get the same error at the end:

```
[nix-shell:~/workspace/idris_tmp]$ idris --listlibs
00prelude-idx.ibc
prelude
00base-idx.ibc
base

[nix-shell:~/workspace/idris_tmp]$ exit
exit
brandon@brandon-750-170se-DevContainer:~/workspace/idris_tmp
$ nix-shell -p 'idrisPackages.with-packages (with idrisPackages; [ contrib effects ])' -p closurecompiler
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/j44rkb0fpxqd4qkamrg1ysf9kbx1q2qa-idris-1.3.0.drv
these paths will be fetched (1.55 MiB download, 4.37 MiB unpacked):
  /nix/store/1fcldlyp5n0ry22dsqfam68mpra6jky9-idris-effects-1.3.0
  /nix/store/a9rjm84pbmvg6dmkdzhl9q1wliyi0q4b-idris-contrib-1.3.0
copying path '/nix/store/a9rjm84pbmvg6dmkdzhl9q1wliyi0q4b-idris-contrib-1.3.0' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
copying path '/nix/store/1fcldlyp5n0ry22dsqfam68mpra6jky9-idris-effects-1.3.0' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
building '/nix/store/j44rkb0fpxqd4qkamrg1ysf9kbx1q2qa-idris-1.3.0.drv'...
/nix/store/5dny6qnjfq9liya5z1sxvr2g64bqypwl-idris-base-1.3.0/nix-support:
propagated-build-inputs: /nix/store/1fcldlyp5n0ry22dsqfam68mpra6jky9-idris-effects-1.3.0/nix-support/propagated-build-inputs
/nix/store/a9rjm84pbmvg6dmkdzhl9q1wliyi0q4b-idris-contrib-1.3.0/nix-support:
propagated-build-inputs: /nix/store/1fcldlyp5n0ry22dsqfam68mpra6jky9-idris-effects-1.3.0/nix-support/propagated-build-inputs
/nix/store/a5x52wi84jgjiimpnkfpcl3mbpbkf1r4-idris-1.3.0/nix-support:
propagated-build-inputs: /nix/store/1fcldlyp5n0ry22dsqfam68mpra6jky9-idris-effects-1.3.0/nix-support/propagated-build-inputs


[nix-shell:~/workspace/idris_tmp]$ idris --listlibs
00effects-idx.ibc
effects
00base-idx.ibc
base
00prelude-idx.ibc
prelude
00contrib-idx.ibc
contrib

[nix-shell:~/workspace/idris_tmp]$ idris --codegen javascript hello.idr -o hello.js
 Can't find import Effects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `-p effects` to your commandline as in

```
idris -p effects --codegen javascript hello.idr -o hello.js
```

this will load the additional library/package. You can avoid doing this by defining an ipkg file, which describes your build. See here: http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/packages.html